# How to customize css style in facebook guestbook plugin (html5 version)?

Tags: css, facebook, html, plugins

When the page is loaded, I can see the huge css code generated by facebook plugin (HTML5) with specific tools like Firebug and I can change it. But how can I change the style without using Firebug?
I tried to overwrite the classes in my css code, but my code is ignored by the plugin.

Answer (score 0):

If by guestbook you mean facebook comments the trick is to wrap it in a div like so:

```
<div id="comments">
    <fb:comments xid="XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" numposts="15"></fb:comments>
</div>
```

Then in your css you can do

```
#comments { 
    width: 100%; 
    float: left; 
    font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; 
    color: #ff6600; 
}
#comments a { color: #ff6600; }
```

And so forth, for full styling information this link should help you
http://www.daddydesign.com/wordpress/how-to-customize-the-facebook-comments-social-plugin-on-a-static-fbml-tab/

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but unfortunately this solution is obsolete. It is valid only for the old method with the iframe , now no longer available. I would need a solution HTLM5

Comment: From what i can tell even the html5 version creates an iframe (atleast in my test example i've set up) so i'm affraid that it is not possible to achieve what you are trying to do :(